# How to get value of transitionDuration in C# for Unity UI Toolkit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui, ui-toolkit

My existing code for this task is:

```
private VisualElement _creditSection;

    private void Start()
    {
        var rootElement = uiDocument.rootVisualElement;
        
        _creditSection = rootElement.Q("CreditSection");

        Debug.Log(_creditSection.style.transitionDuration.value);
    }
```

However, I am receiving null for this in console. I understand it's because the value is of object type, but I don't know how to get the value of the transition duration.

Comment: are you maybe getting `null` for `_creditSection` due to that query `rootElement.Q("CreditSection")` failing? Like is it printing out `null` in the console or do you rather get a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @derHugo I'm sure It's correct. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77999961/16948694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance, I discovered that I am able to get the value of `transitionDuration` using this code:

```
print(_creditSection.resolvedStyle.transitionDuration.First().value);
```

It seems that `_creditSection.style` is used for setting values, whereas `resolvedStyle` is used for getting values. Utilizing LINQ, we can extract the first value of transitionDuration.